# Cherry-pick with customized old SHA-1 line automatically

Tags: git, version-control, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick, commit-message

If I cherry-pick original commit `deadbeef` with [`-x`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick/#git-cherry-pick--x), Git would append a line like

```
(cherry picked from commit deadbeef)
```

Is there any way to customize this message? Like I prefer

```
Backported from: deadbeef
```

Maybe some custom Git alias?

Comment: Use `git cherry-pick -x --edit` while setting the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable to the name of a script that will edit the last line in place.

Comment: @torek I'll accept that as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can always use

```
git commit --amend
```

to change your commit message.

Comment: ...or automate the process via a pre-commit git hook.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention that I want it automated.

Comment: @RomainValeri Git hook looks very promising; how can I amend the message non-interactively?